# MetaCall CLI Installation error on Windows

Tags: windows, dll, mingw

So I'm trying to install the `Metacall CLI` on my Windows machine using their [installation guide](https://core.metacall.io/#/docs/getting-started?id=installation).

However, while running the last step i.e. `cmake --build . --target install`, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\USER>cd core

C:\Users\USER\core>cd build

C:\Users\USER\core\build>cmake --build . --target install
[  1%] Built target version
[  1%] Built target preprocessor
[  2%] Built target environment
[  3%] Built target format
[  4%] Built target backtrace
[  5%] Built target threading
[ 13%] Built target log
[ 15%] Built target memory
[ 16%] Built target portability
[ 18%] Built target adt
[ 19%] Built target filesystem
[ 20%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\libdynlinkd.dll
CMakeFiles\dynlink.dir/objects.a(dynlink_impl_win32.c.obj): In function `dynlink_impl_interface_lib_path_win32':
C:/Users/USER/core/source/dynlink/source/dynlink_impl_win32.c:124: undefined reference to `EnumProcessModules@16'
C:/Users/USER/core/source/dynlink/source/dynlink_impl_win32.c:132: undefined reference to `GetModuleFileNameExA@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
source\dynlink\CMakeFiles\dynlink.dir\build.make:171: recipe for target 'libdynlinkd.dll' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [libdynlinkd.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3839: recipe for target 'source/dynlink/CMakeFiles/dynlink.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [source/dynlink/CMakeFiles/dynlink.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:154: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2

C:\Users\USER\core\build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to build the CLI manually on Windows, consider using the PowerShell installation script.

Run:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command “[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; &([scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing ‘https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metacall/install/master/install.ps1')))"
```